# if $f\left(x+y,\frac{y}{x}\right)= x^2-y^2$ then $f(x,y)=?$

Tags: functions

So, I have to find $f(x,y)$ if the following holds:

$$f\left(x+y,\frac{y}{x}\right)= x^2-y^2$$

I thought about replacing $x+y=X$, and $y/x=Y$, but now where do I replace this $x$ and $y$ that I've found?

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer to this question. It's good policy to wait for a while to see if you get more answers before accepting, but make sure to accept an answer if you got at least one that you liked. Thanks.

Comment: If you get answers that are helpful, you can "accept" one answer per question, but upvote as many as you'd like. To accept an answer, just click on the $\checkmark$ to the left of the answer you'd like to accept.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set $X=x+y,Y=\frac{y}{x}$. Can you solve for $x,y$ as functions of $X,Y$?

Comment: OMG,I confused it with another exercise,this is what I meant..but I still dont know where to replace it..I will edit it,thanks anyway..

Comment: OK, good. you can easily find $x=\frac{X}{1+Y},y=\frac{XY}{1+Y}$, so that $f(X,Y)=\left( \frac{X}{1+Y} \right)^2-\left( \frac{XY}{1+Y} \right)^2$

Comment: Merci monsieur :)